# Group functions with Hierarchical Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table employees(emp_id, name,salary, manager_id)
I want to write query to retrieve manager_id and summation of all salaries of employees who are managed by this manager or even managed by manager who is managed by this manager.
I wrote query like this:

```
Select manager_id , sum(salary) 
from employees 
connect by prior emp_id = manager_id
  start manager_id = 100 
group by manager_id;
```

but that doesn't retrieve sum salary as I want.

Comment: what database do you use?

Comment: `connect by prior` indicates to oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build hierachy first remembering ROOT, then group by root. E.g. salary of the manager which emp_id=100 and all employees he/she managers:

```
SELECT manager_id, SUM(salary) "Total_Salary" 
FROM (
   SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT emp_id as manager_id, Salary
   FROM emploees
   START WITH emp_id=100
   CONNECT BY PRIOR emp_id = manager_id )
GROUP BY manager_id
ORDER BY manager_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

@Serg's solution is fine, but for one manager even simpler query works:

```
select 21 as id, sum(salary) as summed
  from employees e
  start with emp_id = 21
  connect by prior emp_id = manager_id;
```

If you don't want manager's salary in sum then add `where level<>1`.

Test data:

```
create table employees(emp_id number(4), name varchar2(10), 
                       salary number(6), manager_id number(4));

insert into employees values (   1, 'King',   10000, null);
insert into employees values (  11, 'Smith',   8000,    1);
insert into employees values (  21, 'Jones',   9000,    1);
insert into employees values ( 211, 'Brown',   7500,   21);
insert into employees values ( 212, 'Adams',   6200,   21);
insert into employees values (2111, 'White',   5000,  211);
```

Output:

```
    ID     SUMMED
------ ----------
    21      27700
```